# Can't install Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, store

I can't install the windows terminal on my laptop from the Microsoft store.
Error: Try again later, something happened on our end.
Tried installing with App installer, nothing happened after clicking install. I run the store app troubleshooter, and also tried running wsreset.
I am running windows 10 home (21H1) 32 bit.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDTHd.png)

Comment: Further information would be good, did this only happen once or has the installation not worked for several days?
The error message says quite clearly that it is probably a problem at Microsoft. If I were you, I would try again tomorrow.

Comment: I tried again right now, the error is the same as before and I tried to install candy crush and skype the error remained the same. [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/try-again-later-something-happened-at-our-end/56c3a8a7-a391-43ed-bb2e-880ec09809f6?auth=1) trying this, Will update you.

Comment: a service related to Microsoft was disabled, I read it in a Reddit thread, My problem is fixed.